# Tailwind align with Flex (Top, Center, Bottom)

Tags: html, flexbox, tailwind-css

I would like to build the following in a container using tailwind. Unfortunately I haven't found a good solution yet. Maybe someone knows more.

[image]

```
  <div class="bg-blue-200 h-48 flex px-8">
        <div class="flex items-top">1</div>
        <div class="flex items-center">2</div>
        <div class="flex items-end">3</div>
  </div>
```

In the div heading1 one should be at top, heading2 center and heading3 at bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use 'flex-col' class.

```
 <div class="flex flex-col">
      <div class="flex mb-1 bg-blue-200 py-5">Heading 1</div>
      <div class="flex mb-1 bg-blue-200 py-5">Heading 2</div>
      <div class="flex mb-1 bg-blue-200 py-5">Heading 3</div>
  </div>
```

Demo:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/hDdf1puPXP?size=1260x720

Answer (score 1):

This is my proposition with `flex` `flex-col` `items-center` `justify-center` and custom `bg-[colors]` and a little white space (*padding ,margin*). Built with [tailwindcss](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  </head>

  <body class="bg-[#C3C3C3]">
    <div
      class="flex flex-col items-start justify-center h-screen text-transform: uppercase text-4xl text-white gap-40 ml-10"
    >
      <div class="bg-[#898989] py-5 h-20 w-96 pl-5">Heading1</div>
      <div class="bg-[#898989] py-5 h-20 w-96 pl-5">Heading2</div>
      <div class="bg-[#898989] py-5 h-20 w-96 pl-5">Heading3</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```